# Div bottom floating

Tags: html, css

I'm here because I have a problem in positioning an element in my html.

Here's the webpage at issue: http://www.aformulaonehistory.com/test/index.html.

As you can see the website is built in rows, what I have to do is put the text line with the car model and the driver name under the car, in the bottom.

The code of a row is likely:

```
<li id="row1">
    <div class="year">
              text
            </div>
    <div class="car_text">
      <div class="model">
                car model
              </div>
              <div class="driver">
                driver name
              </div>
            </div>
</li>
```

the div I have to move is the one called "car_text". I've tried setting position: absolute and bottom:30px; but in this way all other  called "car_text" are overlapping in the same row!

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` and `top:450px;` to the CSS of `#car_text`

Comment: thanks, that can be a nice solution for average resolutions, but, for example, if seen on a 27 inch screen, the text will overlap the car :)

Comment: How about doing something like `top: 55%`?

Comment: seems to be ok! Thanks man, I'll test this code on a 27" inches screen, I'll let you know!